# Client in Client-Server Chat CPU load 30-50%

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, chat

A client connects to the Server, the server sends to the client 1 message and the client must wait for another message. While client waiting in while(true) loop it loads the CPU to 50%. I try to do this as simple I can to learn how it works.

P.S. All catch() already hiden to minimize code here.

Client:

```
public class SocketClient 
{
   String host;
   int port;
   static Socket connection;
   BufferedReader bfr;

    public SocketClient(String host, int port)
    {
        this.port = port; 
        this.host = host;   
    }

    public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, Exception
    {
        connection = new Socket(new String(host), port);
        System.out.println("Client is ready.");

        bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    }

     public void readInput() throws IOException
     {
           String input;   
           if(input = bfr.readLine()) != null)
           {
               System.out.println(input); 
           }
     }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, Exception 
      {
          SocketClient socketClient = new SocketClient("localhost", 19999);

           try {    
               socketClient.connect();

               try
               {
                  while(true)
                  {
                     socketClient.readInput();
                  }
               }

           }
     }
}
```

Server:

```
   public class MultipleSocketServer implements Runnable {

  private Socket connection;
  private String TimeStamp;
  private int ID;

  static PrintWriter writer;
  private static File file;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
         throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException 
  {

  int port = 19999;
  int count = 0;

  file = new File("E:/test.txt");
  writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");

    try
    {
      ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
      System.out.println("MultipleSocketServer Initialized");

      while (true) 
      {
        Socket connection = socket.accept();
        Runnable runnable = new MultipleSocketServer(connection, ++count);
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
      }
    }
  }


MultipleSocketServer(Socket s, int i) {
  this.connection = s;
  this.ID = i;
}

public void run() {
    try {

      System.out.println("Connected: " + connection.getLocalSocketAddress() + " at port " + connection.getPort());    
      writer.println(ID + ": " + connection.getLocalSocketAddress() + " at port " + connection.getPort());
      writer.flush();


      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
      writer.write("MultipleSocketServer repsonded at " + new java.util.Date().toString());
      writer.write("\n");
      writer.flush(); 

    }
    finally {
      try {
        connection.close();
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question? Please make it clear so we can understand what your problem is and how we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Analysis

It seems the server side closes connection after sending the data.

The client side has the following infinite loop:

```
while (true)
{
    socketClient.readInput();
}
```

The loop can cause the CPU consumption: the method `bfr.readLine()` method call will return `null` **immediately** after the connection is closed.

### Solution

Please consider changing the loop of the client side to read until "the end-of-connection":

```
String input;
while ((input = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(input);
}
```